# Why is eval signaling me the following error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token at HTMLButtonElement. <anonymous> (index.js: 11)

Tags: javascript

I have a question about using `eval` in this little calculator. I get the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
> at HTMLButtonElement.  (index.js: 11)
> (anonymous) @ index.js: 11

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

buttons.forEach((button)=>{
button.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    result.textContent += e.target.id;
   });
});

 equal.addEventListener("click",()=>{
 result.textContent = eval(result.textContent);
});

 clear.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  result.textContent= "";
})
```

```html
<div class="app">
<h3 id="result"></h3>
<button class="btn" id="9">9</button>
<button class="btn" id="8">8</button>
<button class="btn" id="7">7</button>
<button class="btn" id="6">6</button>
<button class="btn" id="5">5</button>
<button class="btn" id="4">4</button>
<button class="btn" id="3">3</button>
<button class="btn" id="2">2</button>
<button class="btn" id="1">1</button>
<button class="btn" id="0">0</button>
<button class="btn" id=".">.</button>
<button class="btn" id="-">-</button>
<button class="btn" id="+">+</button>
<button class="btn" id="equal">=</button>
<button class="btn" id="*">*</button>
<button class="btn" id="/">/</button>
<button class="btn" id="clear">C</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Well if you do `1 + 1` and then press `=`  textContent = `1+1equal`, and that make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `id="equal"` button is one of the buttons you hook up here:

```
buttons.forEach((button)=>{
button.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    result.textContent += e.target.id;
   });
});
```

Since you hooked it up before the other code hooking it up for a different reason, it adds its `equal` ID to the `result` text before trying to `eval` it, which means the result is not valid syntax for JavaScript code (for instance, `5-9equal`).

The minimal fix is to skip it in that loop:

```
buttons.forEach((button)=>{
    if (button.id !== "equal") {
        button.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
            result.textContent += e.target.id;
         });
    }
});
```

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

buttons.forEach((button)=>{
    if (button.id !== "equal") {
        button.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
            result.textContent += e.target.id;
         });
    }
});

equal.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    result.textContent = eval(result.textContent);
});

clear.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    result.textContent= "";
})
```

```html
<div class="app">
<h3 id="result"></h3>
<button class="btn" id="9">9</button>
<button class="btn" id="8">8</button>
<button class="btn" id="7">7</button>
<button class="btn" id="6">6</button>
<button class="btn" id="5">5</button>
<button class="btn" id="4">4</button>
<button class="btn" id="3">3</button>
<button class="btn" id="2">2</button>
<button class="btn" id="1">1</button>
<button class="btn" id="0">0</button>
<button class="btn" id=".">.</button>
<button class="btn" id="-">-</button>
<button class="btn" id="+">+</button>
<button class="btn" id="equal">=</button>
<button class="btn" id="*">*</button>
<button class="btn" id="/">/</button>
<button class="btn" id="clear">C</button>
</div>
```

...or to otherwise leave that button out of the list you're looping through (by putting a different class only on the ones you want to handle in that loop, putting those buttons in a container the `equal` button isn't in, etc).

---

**That said**, in general it's best to avoid `eval` if you can. It's fine if you have absolute control over the text being `eval`d, but since it executes **any** JavaScript code you pass to it (not just math equations), it's important not to use it on any string that you can't absolutely trust didn't come from a malicious source. For instance, if you have an app that allows User A to enter text you're going to use `eval` on, you must not use `eval` on it in User B's browser without User B's express permission and action.